# Finding a location latitude and longitude based on the postal code and country code on google api

Tags: google-api, google-geocoding-api

We need solution of finding a location latitude and longitude based on the postal code, So I have used google geocoding and component filtering. But once for some postal codes(2001,2003,2012,2014 and etc ) doesn't get any result filtered out so can we have solutions for this or will be able find any alternate solution for this.

Here is url which i have try to get json data.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=AU&components=postal_code:2001&sensor=false&key=API-Key

Answer (score 1):

You don't get a result because some of those post codes seem to correspond to postal boxes.

As an alternative you can use geocode.xyz

For example: http://geocode.xyz/2001?region=AU

Australia x,y z: -33.86318,151.20859

SYDNEY, SYDNEY, Australia 2001 » Confidence Score: 0.5

To get json data try: http://geocode.xyz/2001?region=AU&json=1

`{   "standard" : {      "addresst" : "SYDNEY",      "stnumber" : {},      "prov" : "AU",      "city" : "SYDNEY",      "countryname" : "Australia",      "postal" : "2001",      "confidence" : "0.5"   },   "longt" : "151.20859",   "alt" : {      "loc" : {         "streets" : {            "street_address" : {               "staddress" : "SYDNEY",               "stnumber" : "-"            }         },         "longt" : "151.20859",         "city" : "SYDNEY",         "cc" : {},         "latt" : "-33.86318"      }   },   "elevation" : {},   "latt" : "-33.86318"}`

Comment: Yes it works, but if you check these two result, don't not sure information might 100% correct  (http://geocode.xyz/2001?region=AU&json=1) (http://geocode.xyz/2006?region=AU&json=1)

Comment: It can't be 100% correct. These postcodes correspond to p.o. boxes, and are mapped to the city centroid. A complete list of Australian post codes can be found here: https://postcode.auspost.com.au/free_display.html?id=1  (That's how I know these are po box post codes.)

Comment: Postal boxes (PO boxes, CEDEX, etc.) are not supported by the Google Maps APIs. Only postal codes are. See also https://issuetracker.google.com/75985322